# Form is undefined when passing its ID into a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a form which is displayed in a jQuery dialog box. However I am having trouble passing the ID of the form into the dialog window. Here is the output shown by Chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EIa1.png

I know the answer must be obvious but I can't work out why "frmDecline1" wouldn't be available to the JavaScript function?

```
$(function(){
        // Dialog           
        $('#dialog1').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() { 
                    frmDecline1.submit();
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                }, 
                "Cancel": function() { 
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                } 
            }
        });

        // Dialog Link
        $('#dialog_link1').click(function(){
            $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }); 
    });
```

```
<div id="dialog1" title="Decline Record">
        <p>Please enter your reason for declining this record below</p>
        <form id="frmDecline1" name="frmDecline1" method="post" action="index.asp?decline=1,ClockNo=1,JobNo=1">
        <textarea name="txtDecline1" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
        <br>
      </form>
</div>
```

`<a href='#' id='dialog_link1'> Decline </a> <br> <br>`

Comment: Element ids aren't automatically available as global variables. IE does that but not other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you select statement is a bit off.

Read this:

[W3Schools jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

And change this:

```
frmDecline1.submit();
```

To this:

```
$("#frmDecline1").submit();
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbmSW/) for it.

Comment: Bingo! Thats just the ticket :) I wasn't aware of JS Fiddle either, that tool looks extremely useful! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Not sure if this was just an oversight or if you're new to jQuery. But if you're new to jQuery, [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) and jsfiddle combined will make you a jQuery ninja.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a form by simply creating a variable with a name matching its `id`.  You have a few options.

You can access the form via jQuery: `$("#frmDecline1")` or you can access it via plain javascript: `document.forms["frmDecline1"];`